# Trying to get GMSCoordinateBounds from multiple paths

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps-sdk-ios

I have multiple paths from multiple `steps` from google maps API(encoded). I am drawing multiple polylines from those paths. Now, I need some way to get the bounds of all the paths so that I can zoom out and show to the user.

The reason I am making multiple paths is because the google map API returns one encoded string for each path.